# Python loading text with inconsistent format into an array

Tags: python, arrays, text, numpy

I need to be able to read a file and import it into Python. What is causing the problem is that the file is not consistent. This is what is inside the file:

```
             -0.2066687680781E-01 0.4329528510571E+00-0.9011796712875E+00
             -0.4119676724076E-01 0.4006276726723E+00-0.9153143167496E+00
              0.1022378727794E+00 0.2991854846478E+00-0.9487020373344E+00
              0.2066854201257E-01 0.3005275726318E+00-0.9535492062569E+00
              0.4130198806524E-01 0.3341401219368E+00-0.9416180849075E+00
              0.6145291402936E-01 0.3000802397728E+00-0.9519324898720E+00
              0.8211978524923E-01 0.3335199654102E+00-0.9391596317291E+00
              0.6186530366540E-01 0.3671853244305E+00-0.9280881881714E+00
             -0.2066862955689E-01 0.3678680062294E+00-0.9296482801437E+00
              0.2066862955689E-01 0.3678680062294E+00-0.9296482801437E+00
              0.0000000000000E+00 0.3344254791737E+00-0.9424222111702E+00
              0.5163235664368E+00-0.3289847448468E-01-0.8557614684105E+00
              0.5062980055809E+00-0.6575757265091E-01-0.8598478436470E+00
              0.4863796830177E+00-0.3290597721934E-01-0.8731277585030E+00
              0.4844416379929E+00-0.1312004029751E+00-0.8649293184280E+00
              0.4652865529060E+00-0.9858986735344E-01-0.8796525001526E+00
              0.4453650414944E+00-0.6581693142653E-01-0.8929267525673E+00
              0.4761176705360E+00-0.6582681834698E-01-0.8769143819809E+00
```

Most of the time the numbers are divided into three columns, but if it's negative, there is no space and that causes an error when loading it into the Python. This is what I used to load the file:

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
sphere = np.loadtxt("sphererad1.out")
```

This is the error that I get:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 827, in loadtxt
items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0.2899294197559E+00-0.1325698643923E+00
```

I am not able regenerate the data, so I have to figure out how to import it into Python. 
I tried importing into Python using this:

```
opn = open("sphererad1.out")
sphere = opn.readlines()
opn.close()
```

To test breaking it out into each number I tried this:

```
l = sphere[2000]
n = 18
[l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
```

and I get

```
['             -0.24', '73256886005E+00-0.', '6656686961651E-01-', '0.9666430950165E+0', '0\n']
```

There are 13 spaces from left if the first number is negative and 14 spaces from left if first number is positive.

```
n = 1
[l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '-', '0', '.', '2', '4', '7', '3', '2', '5', '6', '8', '8', '6', '0', '0', '5', 'E', '+', '0', '0', '-', '0', '.', '6', '6', '5', '6', '6', '8', '6', '9', '6', '1', '6', '5', '1', 'E', '-', '0', '1', '-', '0', '.', '9', '6', '6', '6', '4', '3', '0', '9', '5', '0', '1', '6', '5', 'E', '+', '0', '0', '\n']
```

How do I get it to ignore the first chunk of whitespace and then break it down into three columns of numbers and make an array?

Comment: You definitely should use `strip()` method (http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: Hint - `len('-0.6582681834698E-01') != 18`: `len('-0.6582681834698E-01') == 20`

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re
for line in open("sphererad1.out"):
    print(list(map(float, re.findall(' *(-?\\d+\\.\\d*[eE][+-]\\d+)', line))))

[-0.02066687680781, 0.4329528510571, -0.9011796712875]
[-0.04119676724076, 0.4006276726723, -0.9153143167496]
[0.1022378727794, 0.2991854846478, -0.9487020373344]
[0.02066854201257, 0.3005275726318, -0.9535492062569]
[0.04130198806524, 0.3341401219368, -0.9416180849075]
[0.06145291402936, 0.3000802397728, -0.951932489872]
[0.08211978524923, 0.3335199654102, -0.9391596317291]
[0.0618653036654, 0.3671853244305, -0.9280881881714]
[-0.02066862955689, 0.3678680062294, -0.9296482801437]
[0.02066862955689, 0.3678680062294, -0.9296482801437]
[0.0, 0.3344254791737, -0.9424222111702]
[0.5163235664368, -0.03289847448468, -0.8557614684105]
[0.5062980055809, -0.06575757265091, -0.859847843647]
[0.4863796830177, -0.03290597721934, -0.873127758503]
[0.4844416379929, -0.1312004029751, -0.864929318428]
[0.465286552906, -0.09858986735344, -0.8796525001526]
[0.4453650414944, -0.06581693142653, -0.8929267525673]
[0.476117670536, -0.06582681834698, -0.8769143819809]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first remove the whitespace at the start (and end) of each line using `string.strip()`, then try breaking it up every 18 characters using the method you've already outlined in your question above.:

```
def parse_line(line):
    return [line[i:i+n].strip() for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

def get_matrix(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [parse_line(line.strip()) for line in f.readlines()]
```

Alternatively, you could tweak your line parsing code so that instead of starting at the 0 index, you start at the 13th index. However, this is a less robust solution, so I would still go with the first.

```
def parse_line(line):
    return [line[i:i+n].strip() for i in range(13, len(l), n)]

def get_matrix(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [parse_line(line) for line in f.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to parse fixed-width files.  The `delimiter` argument can be set to a sequence of field widths.  `autostrip` removes whitespace from the data.

```
numpy.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter=(33, 20, 20), autostrip=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only getting problems with the negative numbers, you could inject a space into each line of the file before each non-exponent negative:

```
import numpy as np
import re

values = []
with open(input) as handle:
    for line in handle:
        values.append(map(float, re.sub(r'(?<![eE])[-]', ' -', line).split()))
values = np.asarray(values)
```

Here I'm using a negative lookbehind assertion to prevent matching `E-`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you trivially slice the string?

```
for line in bad_file:
    print float(line[13:33]), float(line[33:53]), float(line[53:73])
```

Or to get all the data at once:

```
new_data = [
    [float(line[13:33]), float(line[33:53]), float(line[53:73])]
    for line in bad_file
]
```